# Thingsboard server in container fail to start - ERROR: relation "queue" does not exist

Tags: docker, thingsboard

I have created a Docker Thingsboard server on Ubuntu Host with docker-compose.yml
The container had suddenly stopped recently, and I not able re-start it again
The same docker-compose.yml is working in another Ubuntu Host.

So i have really no idea what causing this

```
Thingsboard image: thingsboard/tb-postgres
```

Error:

```
2023-05-24 03:30:02.745 UTC [58] ERROR:  relation "queue" does not exist at character 533
2023-05-24 03:30:02.745 UTC [58] STATEMENT:  select queueentit0_.id as id1_33_, queueentit0_.created_time as created_2_33_, queueentit0_.additional_info as addition3_33_, queueentit0_.consumer_per_partition as consumer4_33_, queueentit0_.name as name5_33_, queueentit0_.pack_processing_timeout as pack_pro6_33_, queueentit0_.partitions as partitio7_33_, queueentit0_.poll_interval as poll_int8_33_, queueentit0_.processing_strategy as processi9_33_, queueentit0_.submit_strategy as submit_10_33_, queueentit0_.tenant_id as tenant_11_33_, queueentit0_.topic as topic12_33_ from queue queueentit0_
2023-05-24 03:30:02,753 [main] WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P01
2023-05-24 03:30:02,753 [main] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ERROR: relation "queue" does not exist
  Position: 533
```